# WCF REST Format Output

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I have a WCF service using REST protocol.

**Code:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHybridService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/hybridservice/compositedata/{value}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(string value);
}

[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    List<Data> data = new List<Data>();

    public CompositeType()
    {
        data.Add(new Data() { Id= 1, Value = "test1" });
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Data> DataList
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}
public class Data
{
    [DataMember(Name = "DataID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Currently it returns the following output:

```
{
  "DataList": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Value": "test1"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I change the `Id` within `DataList` to `DataID`? I tried `[DataMember(Name = "DataID")]` but it doesn't work. I do not want to change the c# property to `DataID` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, I had to declare `Data` class as `[DataContract]`.